# onFailure being called when response status code is http 200 in mootools request.JSON

Tags: javascript, json, tomcat, mootools, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to switch from using the normal mootools request to request.JSON since I'm using exclusively json to communicate between the client and my server.  I have a json request defined as:

```
    var jsonRequest = new Request.JSON({

        url: '/ServletContext/servlet', 
        onRequest: function(){
            // Just a class to make the cursor change to progress
            container.addClass('request-waiting');
        },
        // validationMessages should be a json object containing
        // messages on problems validating user input from server
        onSuccess: function(validationMessages){
            container.removeClass('request-waiting');
        },
        onFailure: function(requestObj){
            container.removeClass('request-waiting');
        }
    }).post({'context': context,'title': title});
```

I'm currently testing this in chrome, and the request is posting fine, and returning an http 200 with the contents I'm expecting; but the onFailure call back keeps getting called.  I'm wondering why the onSuccess method is not being called.

The json string I'm sending back (intentionally) in the response is:

```
"{titleErrors: [], contextErrors: ['Context must be more than 40 characters']}"
```

I'm using mootools 1.3, and tomcat 7.

EDIT:  After going up the mootools stack a bit, I found a call to json.decode and this is failing.  I'm guessing that is because my json string is malformed.  I haven't been using json that long, so that wouldn't surprise me but I would have thought that this would work.  I'm looking into this but if you're able to eyeball my json and see the problem then that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The json was malformed.  I had this:

```
{titleErrors: [], contextErrors: ["Context must be more than 40 characters"]}
```

and it should have been this (note quotes around variable names):

```
{"titleErrors": [], "contextErrors": ["Context must be more than 40 characters"]}
```